# SpringBoot React app redirects requests to login page

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot(3.1.5) / React app, and when I make an `axios` call to the back-end API, I check whether the request was redirected to `/login`, indicating that the session has terminated.

If the API request was redirected, I navigate the browser to the login page, but with a request parameter added, because I want the login page to tell the user their session timed out, e.g. https://localhost:8080/login?reason=sessionTimeout

In my `axios` handler, I use the following redirect

```
window.location.href = response.request.responseURL + "?reason=sessionTimeout";
```

When this happens, I Inspect the browser's Network tab, and I can see that the relocation request *itself* gets redirected (302) to the login page (without the request parameter), so the resulting URL in the browser is https://localhost:8080/login and the login page displays no message.

How can I preserve the request parameter when sending the browser to the login page?

Comment: You can use useNavigate from react-router-dom.